# Visual Studio 2017 cannot find boost_system.lib in cmake project

Tags: boost, cmake, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile my cmake project with boost in Visual Studio 2017 but keep getting the following error:

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'boost_system.lib'
```

Here is an excerpt from my cmake file:

```
project(my_project C CXX)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME     OFF)

add_definitions( -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB )

find_package(Boost 1.68.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

What am I missing?

SOLVED: needed

```
target_link_libraries(my_project ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: You show using include directories from the `find_package(Boost)` but forget to show how do you use libraries defined by that call. (That is, `target_link_libraries` call).

Comment: Thanks, that was it!target_link_libraries(my_project ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to specify the library directories.

The C++ → General → Additional Include Directories parameter is for listing directories where the compiler will search for header files.

You need to tell the linker where to look for libraries to link to. To access this setting, right-click on the project name in the Solution Explorer window, then Properties → Linker → General → Additional Library Directories. Enter \stage\lib here (this is the path where the libraries are located if you build Boost using default options).

For CMake try something like,

```
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Comment: @NikolayKovalenko Well I've never had to deal with Boost on Windows so I'm out of my depth. The point is you need to also tell CMake where the library files are.